# Plotting a stacked Barcharts in python using Pandas/matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a stacked bar plots with each bar represent a state, and within each bar, there are three categories of sales orders by counts: Office supplies, Furniture, and Technology.
if anyone can help one this, just getting started on visuals using python!

[image]

Comment: Show the code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: I think you like more `count` function, so there are never missing values in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have stored the data in a pandas dataframe df -  you can use pandas bar plot to achieve the desired result.

```
df.groupby(['State', 'Category'])['Category'].count().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

You can get more information about bar plot from pandas and matplotlib documentation.

[Matplotlib stacked bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html)

[Pandas bar chart](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

Comment: hmmm, why  [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) ? It is used for count values excluded missing values, so it is best use only if need it.

Comment: thank you! i was just doing group by for just one of them.. this worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with `stacked=True` parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Category':list('ffofofoftoof'),
        'State':list('kkcffccccccc')
})
print (df)
   Category State
0         f     k
1         f     k
2         o     c
3         f     f
4         o     f
5         f     c
6         o     c
7         f     c
8         t     c
9         o     c
10        o     c
11        f     c

df1 = pd.crosstab(df['State'], df['Category'])
print (df1)
Category  f  o  t
State            
c         3  4  1
f         1  1  0
k         2  0  0

df1.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: g]

Comment: @Ellen-YilunWang - hmmm, I think here is better use `pd.crosstab(df['State'], df['Category'])` like `df.groupby(['State', 'Category'])['Category'].count().unstack()`, so I am really curious why prefer it? It is longer code,  working different for missing values and also not replace missing values in output to 0. So it is worse solution.

Comment: @Ellen-YilunWang - It working same only if there is no missing values and if all categories for each State. You can check my sample data for difference of solutions. But it is still up to you, what solution used. If like `groupby`, then correct solution is `df1 = df.groupby(['State', 'Category'])['Category'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)` which working same like `df1 = pd.crosstab(df['State'], df['Category'])`. Godd luck and happy coding ;)

Comment: i guess just because i ve been trying to group by and plot, and i am not familiar with the crosstab. I am not against anything, just new and i know limited things. but I will definitely try new methods. thank you again.